# JavaFX: IllegalStateException: Location is not set

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

Здравствуйте, никак не могу решить проблему. 
Создал окно, в котором есть кнопка, при нажатии на которую должно открываться новое окно. Знаю, что задача тривиальная, но приложение падает с таким исключением:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8413)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:381)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:417)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1771)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set.
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2434)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2409)
    at sample.view.View.showInformation(View.java:16)
    at sample.controller.Controller.showInformation(Controller.java:72)
    ... 58 more
```

Код `Controller.java`:

```
public class Controller {

private static final String JSON_PATH = "people.json";
public ChoiceBox choice_box;
public Button forwardButton;

private Human human = new Human();
private View view = new View();
private ArrayList<Human> humans;
private SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

@FXML
public void initialize() throws IOException, ParseException {
    humans = new ArrayList<>();
    readFromJson(JSON_PATH);
    setPeopleInChoiceBox();
}

private void readFromJson(String jsonPath) throws IOException, ParseException {
    Reader jsonReader = new FileReader(jsonPath);
    JsonArray jsonArray = Json.parse(jsonReader).asObject().get("people").asArray();
    for (JsonValue jsonValue : jsonArray) {
        if (jsonValue.isObject()) {
            addPeople(jsonValue.asObject());
        }
    }
    jsonReader.close();
}

private void addPeople(JsonObject object) throws ParseException {
    human = new Human();
    human.setName(object.getString("name", ""));
    human.setSurname(object.getString("surname", ""));
    human.setPatronymic(object.getString("patronymic", ""));
    human.setAge(object.getInt("age", 0));
    human.setBirthDate(sdf.parse(object.getString("birth", "")));
    human.setEducation(object.getString("education", ""));
    human.setFamilyStatus(object.getString("relationship", ""));
    humans.add(human);
}

private void setPeopleInChoiceBox() {
    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Human human: humans) {
        names.add(human.getSurname() + " " + human.getName() + " " + human.getPatronymic());
    }
    choice_box.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(names));
    choice_box.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();
}

public void showInformation() throws Exception {
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("view.fxml"));
    Parent root1 = fxmlLoader.load(); // падает тут
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
    stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
    stage.setTitle("ABC");
    stage.setScene(new Scene(root1));
    stage.show();
}
```

Приложение падает в строке `Parent root1 = fxmlLoader.load();`, вероятно, что не может найти `view.fxml`. Пробовал много разных способов, в том числе FXMLLoader `fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/view.fxml"));`

Код `sample.fxml:`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>

<Pane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8"
      xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.controller.Controller">
   <children>
      <MenuBar layoutY="2.0">
        <menus>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="О программе" />
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Выход" />
        </menus>
      </MenuBar>
      <Label layoutX="14.0" layoutY="41.0" text="Выберите подозреваемого:" textAlignment="CENTER" />
      <ChoiceBox fx:id="choice_box" layoutX="15.0" layoutY="70.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="207.0" />
      <Button fx:id="forwardButton" layoutX="248.0" layoutY="70.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#showInformation" text="Найти" />
   </children>
</Pane>
```

Код `view.fxml:`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>


<Pane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8"
      xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.controller.Controller">
   <children>
      <Label layoutX="226.0" layoutY="31.0" text="Инфа" />
   </children>
</Pane>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Если** проект собирается с помощью Maven'а, то после сборки он запускается из папки target, при этом все остальные файлы, в том числе *.fxml, в неё не копируются, для этого нужно дополнить pom.xml

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.fxml</include>
                </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй слэш добавить getResource("/view.fxml"));
Так же попробуй прописать имя файла полностью: yourpackagename.view.fxml

Answer (score 0):

Создай папку src/main/resources и в нее помести fxml файл в пакете, с таким же названием, что и пакет главного класса. В главном классе:

```
FXMLLoader  loader  =  new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("view.fxml"));                Parent  root  = loader.load(); 

primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
primaryStage.show()
```